# Get Bluetooth RSSI value on Windows 8 with WIDCOMM SDK

Tags: c++, windows-8, bluetooth, rssi

Anyone succeeded in getting bluetooth rssi value on Windows 8?

I am using WIDCOMM SDK and visual c++ to get rssi value, but it always return 0. What I have done is as follows:
- Scan for list of bluetooth devices around.
- For each device, I run StartDiscovery() to get a list of services on the device. 
- Then I open a RFComm channel to the device and get RSSI value through the GetConnectionStats function.

I have install the latest WIDCOMM SDK and the WIDCOMM software update. My laptop is running windows 8 64bit and has Broadcom bluetooth driver, so it should use the WIDCOMM bluetooth stack.

This is the code that I am using:

```
    void BtScanner::OnDiscoveryComplete (UINT16 nRecs, long lResultCode) {
        CSdpDiscoveryRec sdpRecs[16];
        CBdInfo curDev = mDevList[0];

        ReadDiscoveryRecords(curDev.mBdAddr, 16, sdpRecs, NULL);

        for(int i = 0; i < nRecs; ++i) {
            GUID guid = sdpRecs[i].m_service_guid;

            UINT8 channel;
            if(sdpRecs[i].FindRFCommScn(&channel)) {
                CString tmp;
                tmp.Format(_T("RFCOMM Channel: %d \n"), channel);
                TRACE(tmp);

                if (channel == 1) {
                    CRfCommIf myRF;
                    if (!myRF.AssignScnValue(&guid, channel)) { 
                        TRACE("Failed To Set ScnValue"); 
                        return;
                    }

                    UINT8 sec_level = BTM_SEC_NONE;//BTM_SEC_NONE;
                    if (!myRF.SetSecurityLevel((char *)sdpRecs[i].m_service_name, sec_level, false)) { 
                        WBtRc err = GetExtendedError(); 
                        TRACE("Failed To Set Security Level\r\n"); 
                        return;
                    }

                    CRfCommPort ComPort;
                    CRfCommPort::PORT_RETURN_CODE openRes = ComPort.OpenClient(myRF.GetScn(), curDev.mBdAddr);
                    if (openRes != CRfCommPort::PORT_RETURN_CODE::SUCCESS) { 
                        tmp.Format(_T("Failed To Connect RFCOMM: %d\n"), openRes);
                        TRACE(tmp); 
                        return; 
                    }

                    tBT_CONN_STATS stats;
                    while (true) {
                        ComPort.GetConnectionStats(&stats);
                        CString tmp;
                        tmp.Format(_T("RSSI: %d \n"), stats.Rssi);  
                        TRACE(tmp);

                        BD_ADDR tmpBda;
                        bool connected = ComPort.IsConnected(&tmpBda);
                        tmp.Format(_T("Is connected: %d \n"), connected);
                        TRACE(tmp);

                        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
                    }
                }
            }
         }
    }
```

I changed the channel according to what I received from the device, but it produced the same result. My CBdInfo class is just a struct to store bluetooth's information, such as address and name.

Is this possible to get RSSI value on windows 8? If yes, please tell me what I should do to get the value.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research and I think that it's not possible to get RSSI value on windows vista and newer. I cannot affirm that because I couldn't find any website or documents saying so. But here is what I found:

Based on this tutorial, only WIDCOMM bluetooth stack supports getting RSSI value:
http://controllingtheinter.net/WidcommTutorial.php

However, it seems that windows vista and newer use the 6.x versions of WIDCOMM driver and these versions doesn't support RSSI. It is stated in the WIDCOMM SDK Release note that:

> GetConnectionStats (all classes where present) do not support the RSSI data field in 6.x versions

It is because the 6.x WIDCOMM bluetooth version run on the Microsoft Bluetooth stack.

The WIDCOMM SDK release note can be found here:
http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/sdk.php